# How to rewrite this expression with iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have an expression

```
df_1['result'][df_1['result'].isnull() & df_1['id'].notnull() ] = df_1['M'][df_1['result'].isnull() & df_1['id'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: [0]*len(x))
```

I get the following mistake
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

I am trying to rewrite it like this

```
df_1.iloc[:,'result'][df_1.iloc[:,result].isnull() & df_1.iloc[:,'id'].notnull()] = df_1.iloc[:,'M'][df_1.iloc[:,result].isnull() & df_1.iloc[:,'id'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: [0]*len(x))
```

I get the following mistake

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

But as far as I know I can call columns by name,not by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `loc`:

```
df_1.loc[df_1['result'].isnull() & df_1['id'].notnull(), 'result'] = df_1.loc[df_1['result'].isnull() & df_1['id'].notnull(), 'M'].apply(lambda x: [0]*len(x))
```

Or if that doesn't work add `df_1 = df_1.copy()` before the above line.